# Google Places/Maps API - Quick Facts Text?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to figure out if Google Places (or Maps) API allows me to request the 'Quick Facts' text shown when you search for a city/town on Google Maps. For example, if you search for 'London on Google Maps on desktop, brings back this text in a panel on the left side of the page:

*"London, England’s capital, set on the River Thames, is a 21st-century city with history stretching back to Roman times. At its centre stand the imposing Houses of Parliament, the iconic ‘Big Ben’ clock tower and Westminster Abbey, site of British monarch coronations. Across the Thames, the London Eye observation wheel provides panoramic views of the South Bank cultural complex, and the entire city."*

I know I can get 'description text' back for actual places using Google Places API but I don't think this is the case for towns and cities themselves. Does anyone know how I can get this 'quick facts' text for cities/towns using an API?

Comment: Its an old question but you can get that information from wikipedia api. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=London&origin=*&format=json Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SaveWidget` control to create a custom UI for saving places. When you use the `SaveWidget` you can specify additional attribution data so that you user remembers where they saved the place from and can easily navigate back to your app.

In order to add a SaveWidget to your app, you will need to do the following:

- Add a div to a page that contains a Google Map.
- Indicate the place to be saved with a marker, so that your user knows which place they are saving.
- Create a **SaveWidgetOptions** object that includes a **place** and *attribution* object literal.
- Create a new **SaveWidget** object, passing the **div** and the options that you've added.

Follow this link to show the complete code sample: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget

Comment: Thanks for taking time to replying but this isn't what I need. I need to pull the quick facts text for cities and towns which is displayed when you search for a city/town on google maps and display that as content in my own site

Comment: @Sparky1 did you get any solution? also want to implement same in mobile app.